# Prettier overrides ESLint options

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier, eslintrc

in my `.vscode/settings.json` file I have:

```json
{
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
}
```

In my `.eslintrc.json` I have an option for max-length:

```json
"max-len": ["error", 100],
"semi": ["error", "never"],
"import-newlines/enforce": [
    "error",
    {
        "items": 2,
        "max-len": 100,
        "semi": false
    }
]
```

In a angular service I have an import statement:

```js
import {
  CONNECT_SESSION_USER,
  CREATE_SESSION,
} from 'src/operations/sessionOperations/mutations';
```

Which gives the error:

> Imports must not be broken into multiple lines if there are 2 or less elements

Which is compliant to my ESLint rule, when I save the file the file is correctly formatted but then reformatted incorrectly:

[image]